# ASP.NET Web Optimization - Minification without bundling

Tags: asp.net-mvc, system.web.optimization

Is it possible to use [ASP.NET Web Optimization](http://nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization/1.0.0) for minification without bundling?

Lets say I have a page *Example.cshtml* and corresponding javaScript file for that page *Example.js*. I would like to be able to do something like `@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/Views/Example.js")` which will product minified file when not in debug mode. I could of course maintain many single JavaScript file bundles to do this but it seams like unnecessary chore.

Of course there are [other solutions](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheImportanceAndEaseOfMinifyingYourCSSAndJavaScriptAndOptimizingPNGsForYourBlogOrWebsite.aspx) for javaScript compression but I think that single approach with run-time compression is the best way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to create a bundle with just one file to accomplish this currently.

Comment: tnx Hao, I have been trying to reach you unsuccessfully :) Will you be adding this or is my wish seams unreasonable? I could also accomplish this by creating bundles at run-time by using some naming convention but built in feature sounds better.

Comment: We've gotten this request in the past several times, this feature fits nicely into the asset management work, so it most likely won't happen until we get to that feature.